# Is it possible to write a java class file and then run it

Tags: java, file, .class-file

Something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;
public class WriteClassFile
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("ClassFile.class");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(getFileText());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        ClassFile classFile = new ClassFile();
        classFile.print();
    }
    public static String getFileText()
    {
        return "Êþº¾   4 

     <init> ()V Code LineNumberTable print 
SourceFile ClassFile.java      Works        ClassFile java/lang/Object java/lang/System out Ljava/io/PrintStream; java/io/PrintStream (Ljava/lang/String;)V !                       *· ±    
                   %        ² ¶ ±    

            ";
    }
}

public class ClassFile
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print("Works");
    }
}
```

I have tried runnng this, but I get a Illegal Character Exception. Is It possible to Write a java class file and then run it?

Comment: Maybe uudecoding or similar techniques are interesting for you. Compiling `ClassFile classFile = new ClassFile();` should be hardly possible, as long as no classFile classFile.class exists. Maybe `ClassforName ("Classfile")` or similar, like used by JDBC-Drivers, can help you there. And maybe an interface, which your Classfile promises to fulfill. How else should the Compiler know, that `classFile.print();` should succeed.

Comment: ClassFile was the name of the class that I copied and pasted, and deleted. It works when I don't delete it after I compile it.

Comment: Well, the purpose of this operation is unclear. You need the bytecode, to write the bytes to a file but then you can just use the class directly. I must have overseen, that the ClassFile class is declared at the bottom of your Code, so you have the Source, too, and the compiler can generate it. Binary files can contain all sorts of control characters, which might crash your editor or IDE, so loading them into your Source is not recommendet. And without additional knowledge, what their purpose is, what interface their methods build, I don't see the usefullness, except ...

Comment: … for experimenting, which is of course always a legitimate motive. But without the source and the class already in the class path, I guess this will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  But not the way you are doing it.

1. You don't write a binary file using a Writer.  If you do, you are liable to end up with a corrupted file ... due to the character encoding step mangling your (binary) data.

   Use an OutputStream.
2. I have no idea if that is a well-formed bytecode "file".  I suspect not.  It looks like it has already by mangled by binary -> text "decoding".   And probably copy-and-paste as well (see @Antimony's comment).
3. Assuming that you can manage to get a well-formed classfile into the file system, you may *still* need to instantiate a new classloader before you can load it.  This will certainly be the case if you have previously loaded the class.

A better idea would be to create a custom `Classloader` class, and get it to load the class directly from an in-memory byte array using the projected `defineClass` method.

Comment: Note that a valid classfile will contain numerous null characters, so it is unlikely that you'll be able to copy paste it as text.

Comment: Yes, that's nowhere near a valid class blob. On the brighter side, both FileOutputStream and FileWriter create a nonexistent file, so explicitly calling createNewFile is completely useless.

Comment: Creating a non-existent file is an interesting concept.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigonish_(poem)#Text  :-)

Comment: It was copy and paste